# Invalid data found when processing input when using ffpmeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I want to convert an mp3 audio to an mp4 video with a cover.And i wrote this line of code in terminal.
`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i black.jpg -i sound.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -shortest anhao.mp4`
but got this error,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NeK5.png).I'm new to ffmpeg, and the code is copied from Internet, I really don't konw how to edit it.

i expect converting mp3 to mp4 with an exact picture showing all the time
black.jpg is as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7FHL.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you execute: `ffmpeg -i black.jpg -c:v libx264 anhao.mp4` ?

Comment: @Rotem same error as I pictured. seems something wrong with the picture? but it's a normal jpg, and unbroken

Comment: Try with other "normal jpg". If it's not working the issue is probably related to the version of FFmpeg. What is the version of FFmpeg? You may also share `black.jpg` in your question.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you! Thank you very much! I tried another jpg and it worked. BTW, i still shared black.jpg in my question.

Comment: The JPEG you have shared is unique, because it's a Grayscale JPEG. MediaInfo tool reports `Color space   : Y`. The common color space of JPEG files is YUV. FFmpeg manages to decode other Grayscale JPEG images, so there is some other issue with that specific file.

Comment: @Rotem I see. Now everything is clear. I learned a lot.Thank you :)